# Are public IPs in my Tomato router device list something to worry about?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, tomato

My ISP was recently bought out (O2 by Sky UK) and I have been forced from PPPoE to PPPoA. I've set up a a PPPoA relay using a function on an old TP-Link router I had called "PPP IP Extension", which has enabled me to avoid double-NAT as it passes the public IP address on to my Tomato router (running on an Asus RT-N16).

However, I now have the strange situation where in my Device list on the Tomato router, there are loads (like, hundreds) of "devices" listed, all on vlan2, and all with the MAC address of my TP-Link router:

[image]

I have had a fiddle and run a Linux torrent download and I can see the IPs I'm torrenting with are listed on this device list - so it seems to be any IPs that I've connected to. Google DNS is in there, for example.

Now the questions:

1. What's going on?
2. Should I be worried?

Comment: Those are simply connections to those addresses.  I see no problem because of this behavior.

Comment: But why are they showing in the Device list? Previously (before changing to my current network configuration) the only devices shown here were local LAN devices that the Tomato router had given a DHCP IP address to - which is the behaviour I'd expect...